# Values in JSON is undefinied

Tags: javascript, json

I'm currently rewriting my Discord Bot in JS, and I want to use i18n to make it multilingual.
But with the following code :

```
if (message.content.toLowerCase() === `${PREFIX}uptime`) {
    let days = Math.floor(client.uptime / 86400000);
    let hours = Math.floor(client.uptime / 3600000) % 24;
    let minutes = Math.floor(client.uptime / 60000) % 60;
    let seconds = Math.floor(client.uptime / 1000) % 60;
    return message.channel.send(`***__Beethoven:__***` + i18n.__mf("uptime.result"));
}
```

And the one in JSON file

```
 "uptime": {
    "description": "Vérifiez le uptime du bot",
    "result": "Uptime: `${days} jour(s),${hours} heures, ${minutes} minutes, ${seconds} secondes`"
  },
```

The output put undefinied to all items in {}, I watched some similar question to mine and found this solution

```
var old = JSON.stringify(data).replace(/null/g, '"#"'); //convert to JSON string
var newArray = JSON.parse(old); //convert back to array
```

But isn't it a bit sketchy for replacing 4 data ?
It's my first time using Stack I don't very like to ask a question and prefer to solve a problem by myself but there I'm kinda stuck.
Thanks in advance for your reply.

Comment: You cannot have a JSON file with variables  - you would need to eval the string and that is not recommended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace:

```js
 const fr = { "result": "Uptime: #dd# jour(s), #hh# heure(s), #mm# minute(s), #ss# seconde(s)" };
 let uptime = fr.result;
 let time = [12,30,45,12];
 [...uptime.matchAll(/(#\w{2}#)/g)].forEach((match,i) => uptime = uptime.replace(match[1],time[i]));
 console.log(uptime)
```

Answer (score 0):

So I applied your solution and still got undefined as an output.

```
if (message.content.toLowerCase() === `${PREFIX}uptime`) {
    let days = Math.floor(client.uptime / 86400000);
    let hours = Math.floor(client.uptime / 3600000) % 24;
    let minutes = Math.floor(client.uptime / 60000) % 60;
    let seconds = Math.floor(client.uptime / 1000) % 60;
    let uptime = i18n.__mf("uptime.result");
    let time = [days, hours, minutes, seconds];
    [...uptime.matchAll(/(#\w{2}#)/g)].forEach((match,i) => uptime = uptime.replace(match[1],time[i]));
    return message.channel.send(`***__Beethoven:__***` + uptime);
}
```

I edited the JSON file too

```
"uptime": {
"description": "Vérifiez le uptime du bot",
"result": "Uptime: #dd# jour(s), #hh# heure(s), #mm# minute(s), #ss# seconde(s)"},
```

I didn't implement const fr since it's basically done by i18n.__mf("uptime.result")
Still try to figure out how I failed to implement your code.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to use " just use `

```js
let days = 1;
let hours = 1;
let minutes = 1;
let seconds = 1;
let json = {uptime: {
    "description": "Vérifiez le uptime du bot",
    "result": `Uptime: ${days} jour(s),${hours} heures, ${minutes} minutes, ${seconds} secondes`
  }}
document.getElementById("json").innerHTML=JSON.stringify(json)
```

```html
<p id="json"><p>
```